# MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate - browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo: getting called even when peer's phone is turned off

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, multiplayer, multipeer-connectivity

I am writing a multiplayer iOS app that detects when a player is found in the nearby area using the Multipeer Connectivity framework. My problem is when even when I shut down one of the devices, the other phone can still detect it through:

`-(void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Situation:

When I first start both devices with the app running, both devices can detect each other perfectly. Then, I shut down one of the devices, and restart the app on the other device. The device with the app on still detects the other one through the function above.

How can the browser still detect the other device even when its bluetooth/wifi is off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you stopping advertising before the app moves to the background?